# XPages Bootstrap 3.1.1 and Font-Awesome 4.1.0 combined in a theme not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes, xpages, font-awesome

I added the files for bootstrap and font-awesome to my WebContent folder and modified the urls in the font-awesome .css file as recommended.

Then I created a bootstrap theme, which pulls in all the required bootstrap files (.css, .js), jquery and the font-awesome .css file.

However, when I try to use a font-awesome icon (i-tag with class fa fa-icon-name), the icon is not being rendered (IE8/9 and Firefox 30).

When I deactivate the theme and add the font-awesome .css file as a resource directly to my Xpage, it works.

Might the issue be caused by the order I am pulling in the different files in my theme?

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd" >

<resources>
    <metaData>
        <name>viewport</name>
        <content>width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0</content>
    </metaData>
</resources>

<!-- font awesome -->
    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css</href>
    </resource>

<!-- bootstrap -->
    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <resource>
        <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
        <href>bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js</href>
    </resource>

    <!-- bootstrap css-->
    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css</href>
    </resource>

<!-- jquery -->
<resource>
    <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
    <href>jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js</href>
</resource>

<!-- Add default style classes to buttons and fields -->
    <!-- Button -->
    <control>
        <name>Button.Command</name>
        <property mode="concat">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>btn</value>
        </property>
    </control>

    <!-- Fields -->
    <control>
        <name>ComboBox</name>
        <property mode="concat">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>form-control</value>
        </property>
        <property mode="override">
            <name>showReadonlyAsDisabled</name>
            <value>#{true}</value>
        </property>
    </control>

    <control>
        <name>InputField.EdtiBox</name>
        <property mode="concat">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>form-control</value>
        </property>
        <property mode="override">
            <name>showReadonlyAsDisabled</name>
            <value>#{true}</value>
        </property>
    </control>

    <control>
        <name>InputField.TextArea</name>
        <property mode="concat">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>form-control</value>
        </property>
        <property mode="override">
            <name>showReadonlyAsDisabled</name>
            <value>#{true}</value>
        </property>
    </control>
</theme>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Have you got resource aggregation switched on? That could be breaking things. I know it did for Font Awesome for me, see my comment here http://xpagetips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/five-minutes-to-font-awesome-icons.html

I had to remove the @font-face section from font-awesome.min.css. Then I created a separate CSS called font-awesome-fontFamily.css with the content:

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../../../css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');src:url('../../../css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../../../css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('../../../css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../../../css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

I then added the following into a theme:

```
<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getProperty('xsp.resources.aggregate').equals('false')}">
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css</href>
</resource>

<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getProperty('xsp.resources.aggregate').equals('true')}">
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>font-awesome-fontFamily.css</href>
</resource>

<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getProperty('xsp.resources.aggregate').equals('true')}">
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css</href>
</resource>
```

So it's loading the min.css and font-awesome-fontFamily.css if resource aggregation is switched on, otherwise just the font-awesome.css.

I have a feeling that version of Font Awesome doesn't work on IE8. I had problems with 4.0.3 in IE8, but that might have just been because the application was in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you very much for your response. By resource aggregation you mean the option "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources", correct? Yes, that is turned on. Then the question is, if I add the font-awesome .css file as a resource to an XPage or Custom Control, why does it work? I also tried to use just bootstrap in my theme and added font-awesome as a resource to my XPage, doesn't work either. Just by itself, font-awesome works. I will give your suggestion a try though, thank you again

Comment: I also found that Domino has issues with the URL syntax in the font-awesome CSS files: it doesn't like a syntax like `fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0`. Fix is to replace that. See http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/fontAwesome.xsp

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you very much for your response. Yes, I did change the URLs in both of the font-awesome .css files. It seems that the resource aggregation messes things up only, if CSS and JS is added thru a theme. The reason I come to this conclusion is that, when I add the CSS directly to the XPage or Custom Control as a resource, it works.